# Grouping and sorting dictionary and and adding a key value

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this

```
players = [{'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '9400'},{'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '8400'}, {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '7400'}, {'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '8400'}, {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '7400'}]
```

This list of dictionaries will contain players with positions QB, RB, WR, TE. I need to iterate over the list and group every dictionary by team and position. Then I need to sort every position by salary in descending order. Once I have every dict grouped and sorted I need to iterate back over the list and add a depth key and a value for the position that player is in.

Example:

MIN RBs

```
[{'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '9400', 'Depth': 1,},{'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '8400', 'Depth': 2}, {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '7400', 'Depth': 3}]
```

should be the final results.

I will need to do this for every position - QB, RB, WR, TE. There are not duplicate players, but players may have the same salary in that case the depth would be the same for both players.

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to break it down further

```
players = sorted(players, key=itemgetter('Pos'))
position_groups = dict((key, list(value)) for key, value in itertools.groupby(players,key=itemgetter('Pos')))
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you have a look at itertools ?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have the list grouped by position, but I then need to group those lists by teams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

players = [{'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '9400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '8400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '7400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '8400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '7400'}]

team_and_position = itemgetter('Team', 'Pos')
salary = itemgetter('Salary')

# create groups of positions within a given team
groups = defaultdict(list)
for player in players:
    groups[team_and_position(player)].append(player)

# sort each group by salary in descending order
groups = {k: sorted(group, key=salary, reverse=True) for k, group in groups.items()}

# add depth value to each player
res = {k: [{**player, "Depth": depth} for depth, player in enumerate(group, 1)] for k, group in groups.items()}

# fetch MIN RB
vikings_rb = res[('MIN', 'RB')]

pprint.pprint(vikings_rb)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Depth': 1, 'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '9400', 'Team': 'MIN'},
 {'Depth': 2, 'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '8400', 'Team': 'MIN'},
 {'Depth': 3, 'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '7400', 'Team': 'MIN'}]
```

The first step is to use group the elements of the list by *Team* and *Pos*, for this you could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract the values of the keys:

```
# create groups of positions within a given team
groups = defaultdict(list)
for player in players:
    groups[team_and_position(player)].append(player)
```

The second step is to to sort within each group by salary in descending order:

```
# sort each group by salary in descending order
groups = {k: sorted(group, key=salary, reverse=True) for k, group in groups.items()}
```

The second step could be done in-place but I prefer a dictionary comprehension. Finally use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (starting from 1) to add the depth value to each dictionary:

```
# add depth value to each player
res = {k: [{**player, "Depth": depth} for depth, player in enumerate(group, 1)] for k, group in groups.items()}
```

Again this could be done in-place, doing the following:

```
for group in groups.values():
    for depth, player in enumerate(group, 1):
        player['Depth'] = depth
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to fetch all players, just flatten the values of the dictionary:

```
# fetch ALL players
all_players = [player for group in res.values() for player in group]
pprint.pprint(all_players)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Depth': 1, 'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '9400', 'Team': 'MIN'},
 {'Depth': 2, 'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '8400', 'Team': 'MIN'},
 {'Depth': 3, 'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '7400', 'Team': 'MIN'},
 {'Depth': 1, 'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '8400', 'Team': 'NYG'},
 {'Depth': 2, 'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Salary': '7400', 'Team': 'NYG'}]
```

After this, sort the *all_players* list by any given criteria.

Comment: How could I return every player like you have vikings_rb = res[('Min','RB')], but all_players = # every player in the original list formatted

Comment: @AustinJohnson In any specific order?

Comment: Yes, just as one list of dicts with every player

Comment: @AustinJohnson Updated the answer to fetch all players

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't have any problem with pandas library, it would be the easy solution of your problem.
I didn't get the last part that relates to **Depth** but the solution of the first part should be like this:

```
import pandas as pd

players = [{'Name': 'Player 1', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '9400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '8400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'MIN', 'Salary': '7400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 2', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '8400'},
           {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Pos': 'RB', 'Team': 'NYG', 'Salary': '7400'}]

df_players = pd.DataFrame(players)
df_RBs = df_players[df_players.Pos == 'RB']
print(df_RBs[df_RBs.Team == 'MIN'])
```